# Combine and Query 2 Child object to a Parent Object

Tags: query, relationships, child-to-parent, subquery

I was wondering can you combine 2 child objects to a parent object.

```
SELECT SourceIp FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM User) 
SELECT City FROM LoginGeo WHERE CreatedbyId (SELECT Id from User)
```

Answer (score 1):

`LoginHistory` has a direct relationship to `LoginGeo`, `LoginGeoId`. Assuming what you're interested in is to obtain details of the geolocation for each specific `LoginHistory` record, you can perform a relationship query:

```
SELECT SourceIp, LoginGeo.City FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM User)
```

For details of the object fields and relationships, the [SOAP API Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) for `LoginHistory` is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities), 
                 (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

That should allow you to get results with two inner queries.